# Remove part from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I know that there is a lot of topic about this problem, but I can't solve the problem.

I want to remove /part/ from the URL.
Example:

FROM

```
www.mydomain.com/en/part/title/
```

TO

```
www.mydomain.com/en/title/
```

I managed to remove /part/ from the URL, but I become a 404 ERROR.
Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^en/part/\d+-(.+) /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that I have a Joomla site and I'm creating a Blog. For each   blog story that I have, Joomla added in the URL /part/id-title (id is a number). It doesn't make any sense for my to have the /part/ in the URL. www.mydomain.com/en/title/ doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `/part` from the URL should it exist then you can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/part(.*)$ $1$2
```

Comment: Thank you, the rule works perfectly. But I stil have the same problem, after adding the rule the /part/ disappears from the URL, but I get a 404 Error. May this error be caused by the order of the rules in the .htaccess file?

Comment: @VladFilipas I don't know exactly what the other were intended to do or were actually doing.  In any case, my answer removes `/part` from the URL per your specification.